# Microsoft text to speech change pitch and speaking speed with javascript

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

How to change pitch and speaking speed with javascript same as on example below?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/#features

It should be possible, but I can't find any mention of it in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the "ssml" tab there you'll note that it includes a `<prosody>` node - that's what controls the pitch and speed. Check out [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp#adjust-prosody) about the feature.

If you want to change the rate and pitch using javascript then you'd need to get the resulting audio stream and connect to the [Web Audio API](https://zpl.fi/pitch-shifting-in-web-audio-api/)